# Unused namespace declaration appears after XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

After scouring the net for answers, coming up with "almost" solutions... I decided to reduce the problem to a very simple case.

Consider the following XML snippet:

```
<me:root xmlns:me="http://stackoverflow.com/xml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <me:element>
        <p>Some HTML code here.</p>
    </me:element>
</me:root>
```

Note that the `p` element is of XHTML's namespace, which is the default one for this doc.

Now consider the following simple stylesheet. I want to create an XHTML document, with the contents of `me:element` as the body.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:me="http://stackoverflow.com/xml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="me">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>My Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="me:root/me:element/node()"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I included `exclude-result-prefixes`... But see what I get:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p xmlns:me="http://stackoverflow.com/xml">Some HTML code here.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And what's driving me insane here is why, oh why does `xmlns:me` appears inside the `p` element?

No matter what I tried, I couldn't get stuff to work. I have a strange feeling that the problem is with my `xsl:copy-of` statement.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed explanation and for a complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a strange feeling that the
>   problem is with my `xsl:copy-of`
>   statement.

This is exactly the reason.

**The source XML document contains this fragment**:

```
<me:element> 
    <p>Some HTML code here.</p> 
</me:element>
```

In the XPath data model, namespace nodes are propagated from a root of a subtree to all of its descendents. Therefore, the `<p>` element has the following namespaces:

1. `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`
2. `"http://stackoverflow.com/xml"`
3. `"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`
4. `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`

The last two are **[reserved namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xml-names-20091208/#xmlReserved)** (for the prefixes `xml:` and `xmlns`) and are available to any named node.

The reported problem is due to the fact that by definition the `<xsl:copy-of>` instruction copies all nodes and their complete subtrees with all namespaces belonging to each of the nodes.

**Remember**: the prefixes specified as the value of the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute are excluded only from *literal-result elements*!

**Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:me="http://stackoverflow.com/xml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="me">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
  indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="me:root/me:element/*"/>
      </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<me:root xmlns:me="http://stackoverflow.com/xml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <me:element>
        <p>Some HTML code here.</p>
    </me:element>
</me:root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Some HTML code here.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't be more helpful even if you tried. Thanks Dimitre - excellent explanation. Right to the point.

Comment: I did realize, though, a flaw with this solution: attributes in the HTML elements will not be copied... so I'm trying to cope with that now.

Comment: @Isaac: I just edited my answer to also copy all attributes of an element. Instead of `<xsl:copy-of>` you can use `<xsl:apply-templates>` here and this gives you more flexibility -- you can have templates for processing specific attributes.